# Cocoa - Outputting Array Text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h><br/>
#import "QuestionItem.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool        = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// NSMutableArray    *itemQuestion = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// QuestionItem *newQuestion = [[QuestionItem alloc] init];
[QuestionItem aQuestion:@"Question to be answered" Ans: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Answer", @"Distractor1", @"Distractor2", nil]];

// [newQuestion initWithQuestion:@"Twas Brillig"];
// [newQuestion QuestionInstance:@"Test"];

// [newQuestion initWithAnswerMatrix: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"First", @"Second", nil]];
// [newQuestion AnswerMatrixInstance: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"First", @"Second", nil]];

// [newQuestion initWithQuestionAndAnswer:@"Jumping Jacks" Answer:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"First", @"Second", nil]];

// NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

[pool drain];
return 0;
}

//
//  QuestionItem.h
//  NewQuestions

// I shouldn't be moving around mutables?
// Use NSCopy(ing) instead?

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface QuestionItem : NSObject {

NSString       *question;
NSMutableArray *answerMatrix;
NSDate         *dateCreated;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString           *question;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray     *answerMatrix;

+ (id) aQuestion: (NSString *) qClassParam Ans: (NSMutableArray *) aClassParam;

- (id) init;
// - (id) initWithQuestion:(int)question;
- (id) initWithAnswerMatrix:(NSMutableArray *) answerMatrix;
- (id) initWithQuestionAndAnswer:(NSString *)  question Answer:(NSMutableArray *)answerMatrix;

- (id) QuestionInstance:    (NSString *)       qInstanceParam;
- (id) AnswerMatrixInstance:(NSMutableArray *) amInstanceParam;

@end

//
//  QuestionItem.m
//  NewQuestions
//

#import "QuestionItem.h"

@implementation QuestionItem

@synthesize question, answerMatrix;

+ (id) aQuestion: (NSString *) qClassParam Ans: (NSMutableArray *) aClassParam {

QuestionItem *newQuestionItem = [[self alloc] initWithQuestionAndAnswer:qClassParam Answer: aClassParam];

return newQuestionItem;
}

- (id) init {

    if((self = [super init])) {

        /* initializations go here */
    }

return self;
}

- (id) initWithQuestion: questionParam {

    [self init];
    [self QuestionInstance: questionParam];

    return self;
}

- (id) initWithAnswerMatrix: (NSMutableArray *) answerMatrixParam {

    [self init];
    [self AnswerMatrixInstance:answerMatrixParam];

    return self;
}

- (id) initWithQuestionAndAnswer: (NSString *) questionParam Answer: (NSMutableArray *) answerMatrixParam {

    [self init];
    [self QuestionInstance: questionParam];
    [self AnswerMatrixInstance:answerMatrixParam];

    return self;
}

- (id) QuestionInstance: (NSString *) qInstanceParam {

    NSLog(@"QuestionInstance: %@", qInstanceParam);

    return qInstanceParam;
}

- (id) AnswerMatrixInstance: (NSMutableArray *) amInstanceParam {

    for (int i=0; i < [amInstanceParam count]; i++) {

        NSLog(@"AnswerMatrixInstance: %@", [amInstanceParam objectAtIndex:i]);
    }

    return amInstanceParam;
}

@end
```

Comment: Not an answer, but it looks like you're trying to make a single class do two things, and you should read the documentation about designated initializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override NSObject's description method.  Add something like this to QuestionItem.m

```
- (NSString *)description 
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", question];
}
```

You can build whatever string you want to return in the description method.

Comment: Please help.  May I trouble you for an example?

Comment: Did you try the description code above?  What was the result and what were you expecting?  The description code above will print the question attribute of a QuestionItem anywhere you NSLog a QuestionItem.  To get more detail from the NSLog, change the description method.

Comment: I'll give it a try; outputting the description is straightforward enough.  I just hope I can output a variable number of array elements (from the answerMatrix array) by simply processing the array with a loop.

Comment: I'm having trouble using parameters when overriding NSString's description method.